# Trying to set a button with an image in tableView:editActionsForRowAt:

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Working with Xcode 9.2, in a UITableView, I am setting a button with an image and no text when a cell is left swiped.
Here is the precise code I am using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let myButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") {
        action, index in
        print("myButton was tapped")
    }
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage")!)

    return [myButton]
}
```

It works but the image appears at the bottom of the cell.

**How can I bring it to the center?**

Just in case, here is the image I am using for testing (70x70 pixels):

[image]

And here is how it looks in the table view:

[image]

Comment: That´s weird, it does center for me. Can you upload an image and show how it looks for you and which size do you use for your image?

Comment: I just edited the post to include the test image I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the way. You have to create image with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

```
func swipeCellButtons() -> UIImage 
 {
     let commonWid : CGFloat = 40
     let commonHei : CGFloat = 70 // EACH ROW HEIGHT

     var img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "pause") // TRY IMAGE COLOR WHITE

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: commonWid, height: commonHei), false, UIScreen.main.scale)
     let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
     context!.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
     context!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: commonWid, height: commonHei))
     var img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "pause")!
     img.draw(in: CGRect(x: 5, y: 15, width: 30, height: 30))
     let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

     return newImage
 }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let myButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "") {
        action, index in
        print("myButton was tapped")
    }

    let patternImg = swipeCellButtons()
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: patternImg)

    return [myButton]
}
```

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful and allowed me to make clear progress. I am still not totally done though. I was able to create a convenience function which I call swipeCellImage, following the suggestion inside your answer, but I still have some issue. I reformulated my (new) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554329/working-with-images-in-tablevieweditactionsforrowat